# Erro ao passar parametros da grid view de um form na combo box

Tags: c#, windows

Bom dia, eu tenho um form onde eu consulto meus orçamentos e nele eu possuo uma `grid view`.

Quando eu dou duplo clique na linha da grid ela me abre outro form. Porém não me aparece os dados que esta na linha da minha `grid view` aparece o primeiro item da minha combo.

Esse é o evento e o código que eu uso para fazer abrir no outro form. Esse form é o de consulta:

```
private void dgvOrc_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    frmOrcDomestico formOrc = new frmOrcDomestico();
    formOrc.PreencheDados(dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
    dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
    formOrc.ShowDialog();
}
```

Esse form é o que vai receber os dados do outro.

```
public void PreencheDados(string id, string c, string p, string t, string dom, string data, string l, string d, string pg)
{
    lblId.Text = id;

    comboCliente.Text = c;

    comboProduto.Text = p;

    comboTipoProduto.Text = t;

    lblDomestico.Text = dom;

    lbld.Text = data;

    lblStatus.Text = l;

    textDescricao.Text = d;

    maskValor.Text = pg;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já que está no evento `CellContentDoubleClick` substitua `dgvOrc.SelectedRows[0]` por `dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex]` que é certeza que vai solicitar o valor da linha clicada.

```
    private void dgvOrc_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       frmOrcDomestico formOrc = new frmOrcDomestico();
       formOrc.PreencheDados(
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
         dgvOrc.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
   }
```

Essa linha pode estar errada dependendo de como está o combobox: `comboProduto.Text = p;`

Tente uma dessas linhas:

```
comboProduto.SelectedValue = p;
```

ou

```
comboProduto.SelectedText = p;
```

Comment: Coloquei esse comando, porém continua a não mostrar os meus dados da grid view na minha combo. Ainda aparece o primeiro item da lista da combo

Comment: Já tentou comboTipoProduto.SelectedValue = p ou comboTipoProduto.SelectedText = p ?Acho que é isso então. Precisa ver como está configurado o combox

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa, já coloquei os dois modos e aparece o primeiro item da lista da combo